# stop/start services by VB script

Tags: windows, service, vbscript

I took the following VB script from the following site: http://www.itninja.com/question/how-do-i-stop-start-service-in-vbscript

I make some little change in this VB ( cancel the function )

the target of this VB is to control service – stop or start services

so I try for example to stop the Alerter services

And I can’t understand why service not stops or maybe there are other issues? in the VB script?

```
 '//    Name:    ControlServiceWMI
 '//  Purpose:    Controls services using WMI
 '//    Input:    strComputer        - String    - the computer on which we want to       control the service. Null means local machine
 '//            strService        - String    - the name of the service. If     blank,       the    function will use strDisplayName
 '//            strDisplayName        - String    - the display name of the service.    If   blank, the function will use strService
 '//            strOperation        - String    - the operation for the service: START, STOP, PAUSE or CONTINUE
 '//            intWaitTime        - Integer    - nbr of times to loop (effectively, the nbr of seconds to wait
 '//                              for 'strOperation' to complete
  '//  Output:    strError        - String    - contains error text, if operation fails
  '//  Returns:    True/False
  '// =========================================================================================================

 Dim strComputer 
 Dim strService
 Dim strDisplayName
 Dim strOperation
 Dim intWaitTime
 Dim strError


  strComputer = pc
  strService = Alerter
  strDisplayName = Alerter
  strOperation = "STOP"
  intWaitTime = 3



'// Define WMI *state* constants        these are for the 'State' property
Const WMI_SERVICE_STOPPED                  = "Stopped"
Const WMI_SERVICE_STARTED            = "Running"
Const WMI_SERVICE_START_PENDING            = "Start Pending"
Const WMI_SERVICE_STOP_PENDING            = "Stop Pending"
Const WMI_SERVICE_RUNNING                  = "Running"
Const WMI_SERVICE_CONTINUE_PENDING        = "Continue Pending"
Const WMI_SERVICE_PAUSE_PENDING            = "Pause Pending"
Const WMI_SERVICE_PAUSED                  = "Paused"
Const WMI_SERVICE_ERROR                    = "Unknown"

'// Define WMI *status* constants        these are for the 'Status' property
Const WMI_SERVICE_OK                = "OK"
Const WMI_SERVICE_DEGRADED                = "Degraded"
Const WMI_SERVICE_UNKNOWN                  = "Unknown"
Const WMI_SERVICE_PRED_FAIL            = "Pred Fail"
Const WMI_SERVICE_STARTING                  = "Starting"
Const WMI_SERVICE_STOPPING                  = "Stopping"
Const WMI_SERVICE_SERVICE                  = "Service"    '// ?

'// Define string constants for service methods
Const START_SERVICE                    = "START"
Const STOP_SERVICE                    = "STOP"
Const PAUSE_SERVICE                    = "PAUSE"
Const CONTINUE_SERVICE                = "CONTINUE"
Const SET_AUTOMATIC                = "AUTOMATIC"
Const SET_MANUAL                = "MANUAL"
Const SET_DISABLED                = "DISABLED"

'// Win32_Service Method Return Value Table
Const WMI_Success                = 0 
Const WMI_NotSupported                = 1 
Const WMI_AccessDenied                = 2 
Const WMI_DependentServicesRunning        = 3 
Const WMI_InvalidServiceControl        = 4 
Const WMI_ServiceCannotAcceptControl        = 5 
Const WMI_ServiceNotActive            = 6 
Const WMI_ServiceRequestTimeout        = 7 
Const WMI_UnknownFailure            = 8 
Const WMI_PathNotFound                = 9 
Const WMI_ServiceAlreadyRunning        = 10
Const WMI_ServiceDatabaseLocked        = 11
Const WMI_ServiceDependencyDeleted        = 12
Const WMI_ServiceDependencyFailure        = 13
Const WMI_ServiceDisabled            = 14
Const WMI_ServiceLogonFailure            = 15
Const WMI_ServiceMarkedForDeletion        = 16
Const WMI_ServiceNoThread            = 17
Const WMI_StatusCircularDependency        = 18
Const WMI_StatusDuplicateName            = 19
Const WMI_StatusInvalidName            = 20
Const WMI_StatusInvalidParameter        = 21
Const WMI_StatusInvalidServiceAccount        = 22
Const WMI_StatusServiceExists            = 23
Const WMI_ServiceAlreadyPaused            = 24

'// Build an array of the possible return values
Dim strWMI_ReturnErrors
Dim arrWMI_ReturnErrors

strWMI_ReturnErrors                = ""
strWMI_ReturnErrors                = strWMI_ReturnErrors & "Success,"
strWMI_ReturnErrors                = strWMI_ReturnErrors & "Not Supported,"
strWMI_ReturnErrors                = strWMI_ReturnErrors & "Access Denied," 
strWMI_ReturnErrors                = strWMI_ReturnErrors & "Dependent Services Running,"
strWMI_ReturnErrors                = strWMI_ReturnErrors & "Invalid Service Control,"
strWMI_ReturnErrors                = strWMI_ReturnErrors & "Service Cannot Accept Control,"
strWMI_ReturnErrors                = strWMI_ReturnErrors & "Service Not Active,"
strWMI_ReturnErrors                = strWMI_ReturnErrors & "Service Request Timeout,"
strWMI_ReturnErrors                = strWMI_ReturnErrors & "Unknown Failure,"
strWMI_ReturnErrors                = strWMI_ReturnErrors & "Path Not Found,"
strWMI_ReturnErrors                = strWMI_ReturnErrors & "Service Already Running,"
strWMI_ReturnErrors                = strWMI_ReturnErrors & "Service Database Locked,"
strWMI_ReturnErrors                = strWMI_ReturnErrors & "Service Dependency Deleted,"
strWMI_ReturnErrors                = strWMI_ReturnErrors & "Service Dependency Failure,"
strWMI_ReturnErrors                = strWMI_ReturnErrors & "Service Disabled,"
strWMI_ReturnErrors                = strWMI_ReturnErrors & "Service Logon Failure,"
strWMI_ReturnErrors                = strWMI_ReturnErrors & "Service Marked For Deletion,"
strWMI_ReturnErrors                = strWMI_ReturnErrors & "Service No Thread,"
strWMI_ReturnErrors                = strWMI_ReturnErrors & "Status Circular Dependency,"
strWMI_ReturnErrors                = strWMI_ReturnErrors & "Status Duplicate Name,"
strWMI_ReturnErrors                = strWMI_ReturnErrors & "Status Invalid Name,"
strWMI_ReturnErrors                = strWMI_ReturnErrors & "Status Invalid Parameter,"
strWMI_ReturnErrors                = strWMI_ReturnErrors & "Status Invalid Service Account,"
strWMI_ReturnErrors                = strWMI_ReturnErrors & "Status Service Exists,"
strWMI_ReturnErrors                = strWMI_ReturnErrors & "Service Already Paused"

'// Just in case you left the trailing comma in place...
If Left(strWMI_ReturnErrors, 1) = "," Then
    strWMI_ReturnErrors    = Left(strWMI_ReturnErrors, Len(strWMI_ReturnErrors) - 1)
End If

arrWMI_ReturnErrors                = Split(strWMI_ReturnErrors, ",")

Dim strQuery
Dim objComputer
Dim objServiceList
Dim objService
Dim intCounter
Dim blnServiceReturn

ControlServiceWMI            = False

If Len(strService) = 0 And Len(strDisplayName) = 0 Then
    strMsgText            = ""
    strMsgText            = strMsgText & "Neither the service name or service display name were specified."

End If

On Error Resume Next

'// Get WMI objects and initial variables
'Set objComputer            = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set objComputer            = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

If Err.Number = 0 Then
    '// Only interested in controllable services (i.e. not system services, drivers, etc)
    '// (well, we would be if ANY service set its 'AcceptStop' flag...)
    strQuery            = ""
    strQuery            = strQuery & "Select * From Win32_Service"
    strQuery            = strQuery & " Where "

    If Len(strService) > 0 Then
        strQuery        = strQuery & "Name = '" & strService & "'"
        If Len(strDisplayName) > 0 Then
            strQuery    = strQuery & " And "
            strQuery    = strQuery & "DisplayName = '" & strDisplayName & "'"
        End If
    Else
        strQuery        = strQuery & "DisplayName = '" & strDisplayName & "'"
    End If

    'strQuery            = strQuery & " And "
    'strQuery            = strQuery & "AcceptStop = True"

    Set objServiceList        = objComputer.ExecQuery (strQuery)

    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        If objServiceList.Count > 0 Then
            For Each objService in objServiceList
                '// Determine the operation and carry it out
                With objService
                    Select Case (strOperation)
                        Case SET_AUTOMATIC
                            If (.StartMode <> SET_AUTOMATIC) Then
                                Err.Number = .ChangeStartMode("Automatic")
                                If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                                    Do
                                        If .State = WMI_SERVICE_STARTED Then
                                            Exit Do
                                        End If
                                        Call Sleep(1)
                                        intCounter = intCounter + 1
                                    Loop Until intCounter = intWaitTime    '// We're only going to wait intWaitTime seconds
                                End If
                            End If

                        Case SET_MANUAL
                            If (.StartMode <> SET_MANUAL) Then
                                Err.Number = .ChangeStartMode("Manual")
                                If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                                    Do
                                        If .State = WMI_SERVICE_STARTED Then
                                            Exit Do
                                        End If
                                        Call Sleep(1)
                                        intCounter = intCounter + 1
                                    Loop Until intCounter = intWaitTime    '// We're only going to wait intWaitTime seconds
                                End If
                            End If

                        Case SET_DISABLED
                            If (.StartMode <> SET_DISABLED) Then
                                Err.Number = .ChangeStartMode("Disabled")
                                If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                                    Do
                                        If .State = WMI_SERVICE_STARTED Then
                                            Exit Do
                                        End If
                                        Call Sleep(1)
                                        intCounter = intCounter + 1
                                    Loop Until intCounter = intWaitTime    '// We're only going to wait intWaitTime seconds
                                End If
                            End If

                        Case START_SERVICE      
                            If (.State = WMI_SERVICE_STOPPED) Then
                                Err.Number = .StartService()
                                If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                                    Do
                                        If .State = WMI_SERVICE_STARTED Then
                                            Exit Do
                                        End If
                                        Call Sleep(1)
                                        intCounter = intCounter + 1
                                    Loop Until intCounter = intWaitTime    '// We're only going to wait intWaitTime seconds
                                End If
                            End If

                        Case STOP_SERVICE
                            If (.State = WMI_SERVICE_RUNNING) Or (.State = WMI_SERVICE_PAUSED) Then
                                Err.Number = .StopService()
                                If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                                    Do
                                        If .State = WMI_SERVICE_STOPPED Then
                                            Exit Do
                                        End If
                                        Call Sleep(1)
                                        intCounter = intCounter + 1
                                    Loop Until intCounter = intWaitTime    '// We're only going to wait intWaitTime seconds
                                End If
                            End If

                        Case PAUSE_SERVICE
                            If (.State = WMI_SERVICE_RUNNING) Then
                                Err.Number = .PauseService()
                                If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                                    Do
                                        If .State = WMI_SERVICE_PAUSED Then
                                            Exit Do
                                        End If
                                        Call Sleep(1)
                                        intCounter = intCounter + 1
                                    Loop Until intCounter = intWaitTime    '// We're only going to wait intWaitTime seconds
                                End If
                            End If

                        Case CONTINUE_SERVICE
                            If (.State = WMI_SERVICE_PAUSED) Then
                                Err.Number = .ContinueService()
                                If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                                    Do
                                        If .State = WMI_SERVICE_RUNNING Then
                                            Exit Do
                                        End If
                                        Call Sleep(1)
                                        intCounter = intCounter + 1
                                    Loop Until intCounter = intWaitTime    '// We're only going to wait intWaitTime seconds
                                End If
                            End If
                    End Select
                End With
            Next
        Else
            With Err
                .Description    = "The service name specified "
                .Raise 999

                If Len(strService) > 0 Then
                    If Len(strDisplayName) > 0 Then
                        .Description    = .Description & "'" & strDisplayName & "'" 
                    End If
                Else
                    .Description    = .Description & "=" & strService & "=" 
                End If

                .Description    = .Description & " does not exist." 
                .Source        = "ControlServiceWMI"
            End With
        End If
    End If
End If

If Err.Number = 0 Then
    ControlServiceWMI = True
Else
    '// Loop through the error array and, when you hit what Err.Number is,
    '// drop out and set the appropriate error text
    For intCounter = 0 To UBound(arrWMI_ReturnErrors)
        If Err.Number = intCounter Then
            Err.Description = arrWMI_ReturnErrors(intCounter)
        End If
    Next

    strMsgText = ""
    strMsgText = strMsgText & "Error " & Err.Number & " occured."

    If Len(Err.Description) > 0 Then
        strMsgText = strMsgText & Err.Description
    End If

    strError    = strMsgText
End If

On Error Goto 0



 Sub Sleep(ByVal intDelayInSecs)
'// Sleep is here because, of course, one can't use WScript.Sleep in embedded VBS CAs
Dim datStart
Dim blnTimesUp    

datStart                = Now()
blnTimesUp                = False

While Not blnTimesUp
    If DateDiff("s", datStart, Now()) >= CInt(intDelayInSecs) Then
        blnTimesUp        = True
    End If
Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Throw that code away and start over. Seriously. If all you want to do is starting/stopping services, you'll have more trouble stripping that code down than writing it from scratch.

```
service = "Alerter"

'action = "start"
action = "stop"

Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")

qry = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE Name='" & service & "'"
For Each s In wmi.ExecQuery(qry)
  Select Case action
    Case "start": If s.State = "Stopped" Then s.StartService
    Case "stop" : If s.State = "Running" Then s.StopService
    Case Else   : WScript.Echo "Invalid action: " & action
  End Select
Next
```

If you want to restart a service you need to wait until each operation is complete, because they're running asynchronously (i.e. the call returns immediately while the operation continues in the background). Example:

```
s.StopService
Do Until wmi.ExecQuery(qry & " AND State='Stopped'").Count > 0
  WScript.Sleep 100
Loop
```

Similar for starting the service, only that you check for `State='Running'`.

It may be a good idea to add a timeout to that loop, so that your script won't block indefinitely when the service is hanging.

Comment: but I do stop and start how this code know if services was stopped? before I restart it ? , my target is to restart the services , ( sleep is not solution because some services need allot of time to start/stop )

Comment: something is missing in the code ( I get error object required  s)

Comment: The second code snippet won't run by itself. You need to integrate it into the loop from the first snippet. If you can't get it to work: update your question with your current code.